# Setting DIV's height automatically when it's lower than some specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a DIV to wrap a table to provide the scrolling feature as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/WVjK5/1/

It works fine when the list is big, but when the list is small as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/HJUuA/ you can see that the "Select All" and "Clear All" gets far from the first table which I don't want.

I know that the reason is the fixed height of DIV which is 300px. What I want is that the height of DIV should not be greater than 300px and if it is less than 300px then the DIV's height field should be changed automatically. So that the select all and clear all buttons come just below the table.

```
.tableScroll {
    height: 300px; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may want to just use
`max-height: 300px;`
instead of
`height: 300px;`

Answer (score 1):

Try using max-height

Example from your 2nd JSFiddle:

```
.tableScroll {
    max-height: 300px; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is a good resource for this property http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-height

Answer (score 0):

Just change height to max-height.

http://jsfiddle.net/HJUuA/3/

```
.tableScroll {
    max-height: 300px; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use max-height instead of height.

```
.tableScroll {
    max-height: 300px; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```